# Copy specific file to current directory - Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'

Tags: vbscript

How to Copy specific file to current directory :
I get the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' Permission denied
```

line :5
Char: 1

When running a simple copy:

```
dim fso
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim CurrentDirectory
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
fso.CopyFile "d:\eula.1028.txt", "D:\Back up"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already checked for user permission on destination folder?

I didn't noticed the fact that you didn't specified the name of the file in the destination. It sholud be as follows:

fso.CopyFile "d:\eula.1028.txt", "D:\Back up\eula.1028.txt"

or specify another neew different name for the destination.

Angelo.

Comment: Thanks, now how can I copy that file in Current Directory?

Answer (score 0):

It can be as follows to a specific file to current directory:

```
dim fso
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim CurrentDirectory
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
fso.CopyFile "d:\eula.1028.txt", "CurrentDirectory", True
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this error by not including the last `\` on the destination path.

`D:\Back up` instead of `D:\Back up\`

A little more information about the syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method)